# Extracting points in sf object by attributes in R

Tags: r, select, point, shapefile, r-sf

I created an `sf` object from a point shapefile and would like to create a new object by choosing points with certain attributes only. In that case, only those points which have `"Survey Start"` in the column `Subcategor`. Shifting thinking from `sp`/`rgdal` is hard. Apologies this example is not reproducible, but I hope it is simple enough to answer.

```
data_pts <- st_read("Point.shp")

# I tried two approaches. More traditional, and something tidyvers-ey
field_id_pts <- data_pts[data_pts$Subcategor == "Survey Start",]
field_id_pts <- data_pts %>% select(Subcategor == "Survey Start")
```

None of them work. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Your first option seems fine to me, on the second one try `filter`, `select` just select the column.

Comment: If the first one didn't work, make sure you have `library(sf)` loaded before trying it.

Comment: The first option definitely does not work. I did have `sf` library on (otherwise I could not use the function `st_read`)

Comment: The first one **should** work - `nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("./shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE); nc[ nc$NAME == "Ashe", ]` - I suspect you have another issue.

Comment: is it a `factor`, rather than `character` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `subset` to easily select the points based on the "Subcategor" variable.

```
field_id_pts <- subset(data_pts, data_pts$Subcategor == "Survey Start")
```

Comment: Perfect, as simple as that - great! Thank you